# MySQL : Error Code 1215 : Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, schema

I'm trying to make a simple SQL schema, but I'm having some problem with defining foreign keys. I really don't have that much MySQL knowledge, so I thought I'd ask her for some help. I get Error Code 1215 when I try to create the foreign key `roomID` and 'guestEmail' in the `HotelManagement.Reservation` table creation.

```
CREATE database HotelManagement;

CREATE TABLE HotelManagement.Room (
  roomID            INT not null auto_increment,
  roomTaken        TINYINT(1),
  beds              INT not null,
  size              INT not null,
  roomRank          INT not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(roomID));


CREATE TABLE HotelManagement.HotelTask (
  taskType      INT         not null,
  taskStatus    TINYINT(1)  not null,
  whichRoom        INT         not null,
  note          VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (taskType),
  FOREIGN KEY (whichRoom) REFERENCES HotelManagement.Room(roomID));


CREATE TABLE HotelManagement.Guest (
  firstName           varchar(25)   not null,
  lastName            varchar(25)   not null,
  userPassword        varchar(25)   not null,
  email               varchar(25)   not null,
  reservation       INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (userPassword, email));


CREATE TABLE HotelManagement.Reservation (
  reservationID     INT not null,
  id_room            INT not null,
  guestEmail             varchar(25) not null,
  fromDate          DATE not null,
  toDate            DATE not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (reservationID),
  FOREIGN KEY (guestEmail)  
    REFERENCES HotelManagement.Guest(email),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_room)  
    REFERENCES HotelManagement.Room(roomID)
  );

ALTER TABLE HotelManagement.Guest
    ADD CONSTRAINT res_constr FOREIGN KEY (reservation)
        REFERENCES   HotelManagement.Reservation(reservationID);
```

Updated the .sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the hoteltask table you have already defined a foreign key named roomid. Foreign key names also have to be [unique](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), so just give a different name to the 2nd foreign key or omit the name completely:

> If the CONSTRAINT symbol clause is given, the symbol value, if used,
>   must be unique in the database. A duplicate symbol will result in an
>   error similar to: ERROR 1022 (2300): Can't write; duplicate key in
>   table '#sql- 464_1'. If the clause is not given, or a symbol is not
>   included following the CONSTRAINT keyword, a name for the constraint
>   is created automatically.

UPDATE

The email field in the guest table is the rightmost column of the primary key, this way the pk cannot be used to independently look up email in that table. Either change the order or fields in the pk, or have a separate index on email field in the guest table. Quote from the same link as above:

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

Pls read through the entire documentation I linked before proceeding with creating the fks!

Side note 2 (1st is in the comments below): you should probably have a unique numeric guest id because that is lot more efficient than using email. Even if you decide to stick with email as id, I would restrict the pk in the guest table to email only. With the current pk I can register with the same email multiple times if I use different password.

Comment: Hi, I updated it after reading what you said. But I'm still seeing the same error message even though I'm unsure of what to do at this point. I appreciated your answer though.

Comment: There is a secondary number within the error message that should help you and us to narrow down the issue.

Comment: As a side note: you should not store reservation id in the guest table, since a guest may have multiple reservations.